# Displaying char/number from hex

Tags: c, pointers

Basically, I need my program to display something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaPd6.png

I feel like for the most part, I have the code down. However, I'm having trouble displaying anything between the `||` portion of my code. When I compile, nothing appears in between. The 'format' is supposed to be like this:
`the memory address is on the far left, followed by two groups of eight-byte sequences (each byte is represented with a two-digit hex value), followed by the ASCII representation of the hex bytes placed between the vertical bars on the far right`. If the hex code isn't an ASCII character, I'm to display a period (.).

On to the code, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void DumpMem(void *arrayPtr, int numBytes);

int main()
{
    auto int numBytes;
    auto double *doublePtr;
    auto char *charPtr;
    auto int *intPtr;

    // Doubles
    printf("How many doubles? ");
    scanf("%d", &numBytes);
    doublePtr = malloc(numBytes * sizeof(doublePtr));

    if (NULL == doublePtr)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed!");
    }

    printf("Here's a dynamic array of doubles... \n");
    DumpMem(doublePtr, numBytes);
    free(doublePtr);

    // Chars
    printf("\nHow many chars? \n");
    scanf("%d", &numBytes);
    charPtr = malloc(numBytes * sizeof(charPtr));

    if (NULL == charPtr)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed!");
    }

    printf("Here's a dynamic array of chars... \n");
    DumpMem(charPtr, numBytes);
    free(charPtr);

    // Ints
    printf("\nHow many ints? \n");
    scanf("%d", &numBytes);
    intPtr = malloc(numBytes * sizeof(intPtr));

    if (NULL == intPtr)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed!");
    }

    printf("Here's a dynamic array of ints... \n");
    DumpMem(intPtr, numBytes);
    free(intPtr);
}

void DumpMem(void *arrayPtr, int numBytes)
{
    auto unsigned char *startPtr = arrayPtr;
    auto unsigned char *ptrOne = startPtr;
    auto unsigned char *endPtr = arrayPtr + numBytes;
    auto int counter = 0;

    printf("%p  ", &startPtr);

    for (; startPtr < endPtr; startPtr++)
    {
        printf("%02x ", *startPtr);
        counter++;

        if (counter == 16)
        {
            printf("|");
            for(; ptrOne < 16; ptrOne++)
            {
                if (isalpha(*ptrOne))
                {
                    printf("%c", *ptrOne);
                }
                else if (isdigit(*ptrOne))
                {
                    printf("%d", *ptrOne);
                }
                else if (ispunct(*ptrOne))
                {
                    printf("%c", *ptrOne);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf(".");
                }
            }
            printf("|");

            printf("\n");
            printf("%p  ", &startPtr);
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

So, thoughts? Help, please!

Comment: Why are you using `auto`?

Comment: Check to see if you're getting into any of the `if` cases.  What about checking the value of the character and printing it if it's in the right range (like 32-127 or whatever you need)?

Comment: I'm using auto because our professor uses it and he requires it.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be your problem.  You are comparing a pointer to an integer and that pointer is almost certain going to be greater than 16 so you never enter the loop to print anything.

```
for (; ptrOne < 16; ptrOne++)
```

Something like this, however, prints.

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 16; i++, ptrOne++)
```

Comment: Thank you, that completely slipped my mind and I've changed my code accordingly. However, if hex output (middle column) is < 16, how do I make it so that it shows the way it's supposed to on the example output?

Comment: The simplest way in this pgm's case is to always round up you malloc to the next multiple of 16.  Then you don't have to code anything special.

Comment: I thought about that, but that would go against the guidelines. Basically, I'm to have my output look exactly like the sample output in terms of format.

Comment: And sometimes my output is different as well: http://i.imgur.com/xniOE9O.png Note that sometimes between the `| |` characters, there are more than 16 characters. And my memory column (left side) never changes.

Comment: This sounds like homework so I am reluctant to provide too much.  Some other obvious errors: (1) your mallocs are multiplying the size of a pointer as opposed to the size of the type; (2) everything you are printing is a char (%c) so using %d is wrong; (3) `printf("%p  ", &startPtr);` prints the address of the pointer rather than the address of what is being point *to*, which is what you want on the left hand side.  You might want to consider where you place that statement too.